# Passing ArrayList as method argument provides error java.lang.NoSuchMethodErro at launch

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, parameters

I have already check on the net for 1 hour approximately and I cannot figure out why do I got this error message when I launch my program (the compilation seems to work perfectly).

> (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   RequestHandler.verifyRequest(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)

I have a classe RequesHandler, with a method `verifyRequest(ArrayList <String> req_lines)`

Here is the code of my class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class RequestHandler {

    public boolean verifyRequest(ArrayList <String> req_lines) {

    int nb = req_lines.size();

    String first_line = req_lines.get(0);
    if(!checkFirstLine(first_line)) 
        return false;
   .....
    }
```

And here the lines invoking the method `verifyRequest` situated in a `class Worker extends Thread` which imports java.io.* java.net.* and java.util.*

```
            ArrayList<String> req_lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            RequestHandler rqhand = new RequestHandler();

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                line_nbr++;
                req_lines.add(line);
                msg += line + "\n\r"; 
            }

            boolean valid;
            valid = rqhand.verifyRequest(req_lines);
```

I have read about copying but I don t think it is the problem in my case as I do not try to modify the elements of the array list in my code... Is that it ? I have also read about bad list initialisation but I think I did it well ...

Can somebody help me please ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: As you can imagine, in order to not provide a too long code I only put lines that I think are responsible of the error.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant `import` in your classes ? How are you building your program ?

Comment: How do you import the class? Could you navigate to the top of the second class and see the imports, especially the one for RequestHandler?

Comment: I did not import my class RequestHandler.java as both class are situted in the same repertory. Was that responsible of this error message ? Why did it not appear at compilation ? I built the program using basic line command under Linux : javac maclasse.java 
Thank you a lot for your help and your time guys !

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this error is that there are two classes with the same name on the classpath. This can happen, for example, when you move classes from one project to another and forget to properly clean and build the original project or when you still use an old version of the original project's JAR.